# How do I take one dataset and split it into two in SAS

Tags: sas

Hey I have a data set that includes the id of a firm (Permno) and the declaration date as well as a matched firm id and declaration date. How could I make it so that the matched permno and declaration date get put in the same columns as the normal permno and declaration date?

[image]

Comment: How is that "spitting into two"?  What are the two datasets you want out from the photograph you posted?  Note: Please post text as text and not photographs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a data step with a `set` statement or use a `union` in proc sql.

```
data dsn1;
  set firm(keep=permno dlcrdt)
      firm(keep=matched_permno matched_dclrdt 
                 rename=(matched_permno=permno matched_dclrdt=dclrdt));
run;
```

Or

```
Proc sql;
    Create table dsn2 as
    select permno dlcrdt from firm
    union all
    select matched_permno matched_dclrdt
    from firm;
quit;
```

Comment: Ok sorry for the followup but if I wanted to add a variable that retained that identity like say variable new = 1 for the matched permno and new = 0 for the matched permno would I be able to do that?